# Why do my POST requests not get proxy_passed by nginx to my nodejs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

When I attempt to POST from my Node.js app to '/' I receive a "directory index of "/home/" is forbidden, but I'm not sure why nginx is even attempting to handle that request directly? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the output from the log. Some additional debugging suggests that the POST isn't making to my app at all.

nginx config:

```
upstream appname {
    sever localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    error_log /etc/nginx/debug.log;
    rewrite_log on;
    root /home/;
    sever_name mydomain.name;

    location /appname/ {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://appname/;
    }
}
```

If I make my location '/' it works flawlessly, of course.

In node it's not even getting as far as

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
```

But

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, '../views')})
});
```

Works as expected and returns the correct resource.

Why would my POST requests (seemingly) be not getting proxy passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your nodejs app redirecting to `/home/` after the POST, but didn't aware that it has been proxied and being called with `/appname/`, you should make your application aware about the namespace. And make it to redirect properly to `/appname/home/` instead.

Comment: So this was technically correct, but as I accept, let me explain why for people stumbling across this post.

All of my resources and ajax requests were being done like

'$.ajax
url: "/"'

or 

'<link href="/stylesheets/someresource.css" rel="stylesheet">'

The leading / was directing the requests to the specified root in nginx. The issue I was having was trying to fix it in the node app, when everything was in my client side js.